# Reading user input in Java

Tags: java

I need to design and implement an application called CinemaPrice to determine how much a person pays to go the the cinema. The program should generate an age from 1 - 100 using the Random class and prompt the user for the full ticket price. Then display the appropriate ticket price using the currency format (an example in your book ).  You may want to refer to the example we did together in class to help you with the "if statement". Decide ticket price on the following basis:
1. under 5, free;
2. aged 5 to 12, half price; 
3. aged 13 to 54, full price; 
4. aged 55, or over, free.

I would really like some help on this I'm new to java and been spending hours on this now I would love to finish it :)
This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  //Needed for the Scanner class
import java.util.Random;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class CinemaPrice
{    
public static void main(String[] args)  //all the action happens here!    
{  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int age = 0;
    double priceNumber = 0.00;


    Random generator = new Random();
    age = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;


    if ((age <= 5) || (age >=55) {
        priceNumber = 0.0;
    }else if (age <= 12){
        priceNumber = 12.50;
    }else {
        system.out.println("Sorry, But the age supplied was invalid.");
    }
    if (priceNumber <= 0.0) {
        System.out.println("The person age " + age + " is free!);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Price for the person age " + age + "is: $" + priceNumber);
    }
} //end of the main method 

} // end of the class
```

I don't know how to prompt and read input from a user though - can you help?

Comment: This is homework.....

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @DavidHope I'm trying to get the output to be Please enter the cinema ticket price: 12.50 Your age : 1 Your ticket price is $0.00 which is free.

Comment: @Tim I am trying to get the outputs to be: Please enter the cinema ticket price: 12.50 Your age : 1                                    Your ticket price is $0.00 which is free.                                                             Please enter the cinema ticket price: 14.75 Your age : 47          Your ticket price is $14.75 which is full price.                     I don't understant what else I have to do exactly I have to prompt the user to enter an age

Comment: Is any of this extra stuff strictly relevant to your real question then? Is all you truly want getting input from the keyboard into a variable?

Comment: @RichardTingle do you think this would work how it is after I put in the scanner stuff? Im also not sure how to do that with the double that is with ticketprice

Comment: this line of your code already prompted user for input                  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); all you need to do is parse the user input i.e.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue that I see is that you need to update your conditional statement here as anything from 13 to 54 will be an invalid age...

```
if ((age <= 5) || (age >=55) {
    priceNumber = 0.0;
}else if (age <= 12){
    priceNumber = 12.50;
}else if (age < 55){
   //whatever this ticket price is
}else {
    system.out.println("Sorry, But the age supplied was invalid.");
}
```

Something like that would work...

Comment: alright thanks fixed that, I need to prompt the user to enter values for the ticketprice and age but not sure how to do that would I do that after the else statement?

Answer (score 0):

You have stated that your real problem is getting data into your program, the following should demonstrate using the Scanner class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter an age");

    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

    int age=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Your age was " + age);

    double price=scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Your price was " +  price);

}
```

Now thats the basic idea, but if you provide an incorrect input (like a word) you can get an exception, you can however check that the input you're getting is correct and only accept it if its what you want, like this;

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter an age");

        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);


        while (!scan.hasNextInt()) { //ask if the scanner has "something we want"
            System.out.println("Invalid age");
            System.out.println("Enter an age");
            scan.next(); //it doesn't have what we want, demand annother
        }
        int age = scan.nextInt(); //we finally got what we wanted, use it


        System.out.println("Your age was " + age);

    }

}
```